# printf floating-point output variations only with alpine docker on Windows

Tags: c, docker, floating-point, alpine-linux

I ran across some variations in floating point output from printf, but only when running in a node:lts-alpine3.19 (imageid ae7f6c370720) container in Docker (engine 25.0.3, desktop 4.28.0) on Windows 10 (22H2 build 19045.4170)

Steps to reproduce:

- Install WSL 2
- Install Docker Desktop
- Run this:

```
docker run -it node:lts-alpine3.19 /bin/sh
cat > aa.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        double val = 1.2;
        printf("%lf\n", val);
}
EOF
gcc aa.c -o aa
./aa   # Emits 1.200000 as expected
valgrind ./aa 2> /dev/null   # Emits 1.199999
```

Further testing shows that it works fine in a debian:bookworm container, both with the valgrind package (3.19.0) and valgrind installed from source (3.22.0, to match the alpine container)
It also works fine in a node:lts-alpine3.19 container running on an Amazon Linux VM instead of Windows.

I've narrowed this down to variations in printf output, the underlying bit pattern of the double value is the same, as shown by this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        char ddchar[] = { 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0xf3, 0x3f }; // aka 1.2
        double *ddv = (double *)ddchar;
        printf("ddv %lf\n", *ddv);
}
```

Can anyone explain why this variation occurs, and why it happens *only* in this particular environment?

Comment: Floating point is not a precise representation, and will likely vary by a small amount (termed *gamma*) depending on how the value is stored. This is particularly true for some values like 1.2 that do not lend themselves to being represented without a bit of jitter. Do you want fixed point for deterministic output?

Comment: Both values are "expected", since what's stored in `val` is not 1.2 but the closest floating point number to 1.2, and `printf()` has a certain amount of latitude in interpreting that. That doesn't address why there are different `printf()` implementations happening, though.

Comment: Do you get different results with more deliberate rounding like `%.3f`?

Comment: Does it matter what optimization level you use? What if you run `strace --trace=write ./aa` and `strace --trace=write valgrind ./aa`? Do you see `write(1, "1.200000\n", ...` in the non-valgrind run (and not in the valgrind run)?

Comment: @Eric, Please replace `printf("%lf\n", val);` with `printf("%a %la %lf\n", val, val, val);` and report your results.

Comment: The results are also different (w/ vs w/o valgrind) with %.3f.   (i.e. 1.199 vs. 1.200)  Different optimization levels don't seem to make a difference.  With strace, (tweaked slightly to also include writev) I see "1.200000" only in the non-valgrind output.

Comment: The output of %a and %la is always "0x1.3333333333333p+0", even in the valgrind case when %lf emits 1.199999.

Comment: Valgrind is a tool for finding bugs. The fact the output varies with Valgrind means Valgrind has exposed a bug in something involved: your program, the compiler, the `printf` implementation, the execution environment, or Valgrind. Try various Valgrind options to see if you can narrow it down. E.g., turn the Valgrind memcheck tool off.

Comment: @tadman: Do not blame floating-point for a problem just because some floating-point displays are incorrect. The fact floating-point operations round results to representable values does not mean things fluctuate arbitrarily.

Comment: @tadman: Do not blame floating-point for a problem just because some floating-point displays are incorrect. The fact floating-point operations round results to representable values does not mean things fluctuate arbitrarily. `printf` implementations generally round to the nearest representable value and do not have trouble with this unless a large number of digits are requested, and six is not a large number. The symptoms clearly point to a bug, not floating-point representation issues.